# Mysql 5.7.20 trigger error

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to tables a **school table** and a **history table**, in my school table I have a status_id column, so what I want is every time status_id column gets updated I want to post that **status_id** and **school_id** the to **histories table**.

This is what I have tried:

```
DELIMITER ;;
  CREATE trigger homestead.statustrigger 
  AFTER UPDATE ON homestead.schools
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    IF NOT NEW.status_id <=> OLD.status_id
    INSERT INTO histories (status_id, schools_id)
    VALUES (1, 1);
  END
DELIMITER;
```

When I run this query I get this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO histories (status_id, school_id)
    VALUES (1, 1);
END
DELIMITER' at line 6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IF` syntax is wrong and you declare a `DELIMITER` which then you do not use, this should work:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS homestead.statustrigger  $$

CREATE trigger homestead.statustrigger 
AFTER UPDATE ON homestead.schools
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NOT NEW.status_id <=> OLD.status_id THEN
    INSERT INTO histories (status_id, churches_id)
    VALUES (1, 1);
  END IF;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Okay I dont get an error now, but nothing is being inserted now?

Comment: Well, that might be due to the trigger condition not being verified ... is `status_id` different?

Comment: what do you mean is status_id different?

Comment: I would expect you to understand what the trigger body actually does: after the update, if the new `status_id` is different than previous `status_id`, then the insert is performed; but if that field didn't change value, then no insert happens ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167560/discussion-between-peter-barnes-and-matteo-tassinari).

Answer (score 0):

Your If condition is not correct syntactically.
As you are using Insert statement then use Before Insert

```
  CREATE trigger homestead.statustrigger 
  BEFORE INSERT ON homestead.schools
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    IF NOT NEW.status_id <=> OLD.status_id Then
    INSERT INTO histories (status_id, churches_id)
    VALUES (1, 1);
    END IF;
  END;
```

Comment: When I run your code I get this error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER' at line 10

Comment: Hmm I get this error now : [ERROR in query 1] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7
[ERROR in query 2] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF' at line 1
[ERROR in query 3] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 1

Comment: I get this error : [ERROR in query 1] There is no OLD row in on INSERT trigger
[ERROR in query 2] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF' at line 1
[ERROR in query 3] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

You set `DELIMITER` to `;;`. So either remove `DELIMITER ;;` or append `;;` at the end of trigger definition like

```
CREATE trigger homestead.statustrigger
   AFTER UPDATE ON homestead.schools
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NOT NEW.status_id <=> OLD.status_id THEN
    INSERT INTO histories (status_id, churches_id)
    VALUES (1, 1);
  END IF;
END;;
```

Comment: I get this error:[ERROR in query 1] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO histories (status_id, churches_id)
    VALUES (1, 1)' at line 6
[ERROR in query 2] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF' at line 1
[ERROR in query 3] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 1